# How to run test suite in python setup.py

Tags: python, unit-testing, setuptools, test-suite

I am trying to setup a Python package using `setup.py`. My directory structure looks like this:

```
setup.py
baxter/
  __init__.py
  baxter.py
tests/
  test_baxter.py
```

Here is `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(name='baxter',
      version='1.0',
      packages=find_packages()
      )
```

I first do a `python setup.py build`. When I then run `python setup.py test` I immediately get this result:

```
running test
```

and nothing else. The unit tests have not run since the tests take at least 15 seconds to finish and the message `running test` comes back right away.

So it appears that `python setup.py test` is not finding the unit tests. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Fun thing - I'm not sure if that's correct, but i have `tests_require=['pytest']` in my `setup()`, and another difference: my `tests` is under the package directory. And it works without any extra configuration. O, wait, in `setup.cfg`, I've got `[aliases] test = pytest`. Try moving `tests` to `baxter/tests`, maybe.

Answer (score 12):

Pretty simple, add the following to your setup() call:

```
test_suite="tests",
```

Comment: Where `tests` is the name of the directory containing the test suite. The system automatically finds the test cases.

Comment: Errata: not of the *directory*, but of the *package*.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Is this _still_ applicable for at this time (2018) for Python 3?