# Getting the `python setup.py test` syntax to work?

Tags: python, unit-testing, distutils, setup.py, python-unittest

How do I get `python setup.py test` to work? - Current output:

```
$ python setup.py test  # also tried: `python setup.py tests`
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: \
                           UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'test_suite'
  warnings.warn(msg)
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: invalid command 'test'
```

#### proj_name/setup.py

```py
from distutils.core import setup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(name='foo', version='0.1', package_dir={'foo': 'utils'},
          test_suite='tests')
```

#### proj_name/tests/foo_test.py

```py
from unittest import TestCase, main as unittest_main


class TestTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_foo(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
        self.assertFalse(False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest_main()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`test_suite` is a feature of [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#test-build-package-and-run-a-unittest-suite). Replace distutils with it:

```
from setuptools import setup
```

Comment: Your `test_suite` should probably contain `proj_name.tests`, as the documentation suggests.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941880/how-to-run-test-suite-in-python-setup-py